# j-spring-security The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring, spring-security

i had created login authentication using the spring security framework..
when i include the `<!-- Spring Security --> b`elow entries in the web.xml the index page is not shown, also if i don't include the tag `(<!-- Spring Security -->)`, the index page is shown, when i enter the userid/password and click on the submit button, i get the error

```
error without adding <!-- spring security --> tag
---------------------------------------------------- 
            http://sgv09946224.gbl.ad.hedani.net:8080/SpringMVCExample/j_spring_security_check

HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.


error while adding <!-- spring security --> tag
----------------------------------------------------

http://sgv09946224.gbl.ad.hedani.net:8080/SpringMVCExample/

HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCExample/
type Status report
message /SpringMVCExample/
description The requested resource is not available.
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>SpringMVCExample</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml /WEB-INF/mvc-security.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!--  
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here:
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/>  -->


    <mvc:resources mapping="/SpringMVCExample/resources/**" location="SpringMVCExample/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### mvc-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

   <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/showMessage"
            authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="l1" password="l1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

### index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="/SpringMVCExample/images/SupportDashboard.jpg"/>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                Your login attempt was not successful, try again
        </c:if>

        <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"   method='POST'>

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </form>

        <c:url value="/showMessage.html" var="messageUrl" />
        <a href="${messageUrl}">Click to enter</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

### showmessage.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

### spring/application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and add your base-package here:
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/>  -->

<!-- hibernate configuration and mappings 
<import resource="mvc-security.xml"/> -->

</beans>
```

### maincontroller.java

```
package com.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.validation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

/*
 * author: Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/showMessage")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        System.out.println("inisde showmessage method");
        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>" + 
                         "<h3>********** Welcome to LDO Support Landing page **********<h3> </div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("showMessage", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView index() {

        System.out.println("inisde index method");
        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>" + 
                         "<h3>********** Welcome to LDO Support Landing page **********<h3> </div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("showMessage", "message", message);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/fail2login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("inisde fail2login method");
        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("inisde logout method");
        return "login";

    }

}
```

### modified web.xml which worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-*.xml,
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Of course it won't show up, it is protected and it is your login page which is again protected... So how on earth should it be displayed?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting your answer

Comment: M. Deinum wants to say that your login page is : login-page="/index". In the same time, you do : intercept-url pattern="/index*" which means that the login page is secured, you cannot get it if you're not connected.

Comment: Thanks Deinum / Boutaya i even created new page for login but still no luck                                                                                            <security:http auto-config="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <security:form-login login-page="/welcome" default-target-url="/showMessage"
   authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
 </security:http>

Comment: don't add code, xml, stack traces as comments, update/improve your original question that way it remains readable.

Comment: Your `mvc-security.xml` must be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` not the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: many great Thanks  Deinum, you are great, your solution worked for me...

Comment: Hey Deinum, sometime the http://sgv09946224.gbl.ad.hedani.net:8080/SpringMVCExample redirects correctly to the page http://sgv09946224.gbl.ad.hedani.net:8080/SpringMVCExample/welcome.html other time it goes to the index page http://sgv09946224.gbl.ad.hedani.net:8080/SpringMVCExample/index.html any reason on this.,